# 18.04 vlc opening multiple files

Tags: 18.04, vlc, filemanager

I want vlc to open multiple instances if I open the app myself, but I want it to only open one instance if I select multiple files from the file explorer.

Previously (16.04) I think I had it working with this line in /usr/share/applications/vlc.desktop:

/usr/bin/vlc --started-from-file %U

And it does open only one instance if I open it with vlc --started-from-file file1 file2, but it does not work from the file explorer.

How can I make it work again in 18.04 ?

Thanks